# Magento - How to hide URL key of each page?

Tags: url, magento, key

Is there a way to hide the URL key for each page in Magento?  For example a site URL www.test.com/Logitech-bluetooth-keyboard.  Can I disable or hide the URL key so it is www.test.com for every page?

I'm using Magento Community 1.7.0

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: No. I'm curious why you would want to do something like that, from a user's perspective it would be bad usability, and very bad SEO since you would only be able to Google your homepage.

What you could do is to rewrite the whole thing so all links would load Ajax requests instead. This would take some serious time and effort and I don't think it's worth it because I fail to see the benefits of it.

Comment: The reason I thought about doing this is because it is strictly a deal a day site.  I'll have like 4 deals a day and they switch every 24hrs and those previous products would be gone.  So to clarify, I was thinking the URL key wouldn't really be needed as its a one and done product.  I would not want to hide for example the FAQ, Contact Us, Privacy Policy, etc...pages.  My main page would have the main deal of the day so I'd want it to be like www.test.com rather than www.test.com/logitech-blah-blah.  I assume I could do ajax requests just on this page

Comment: Confuse-a-router incorporated. The router knows the page exists because it's representational URL-key is in the URL. Since they'll be gone, simply set the robots meta on these pages to be noindex, follow. Google will include everything but those pages. You can set that in the layout.

Comment: "Since they'll be gone" - badly formed wording as I was referring to the page, not the URL key, it should be, "Since your pages are short term and will soon be gone"